# WebView is closing when I press the button back android keyboard

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

I'm trying to program for android and I'm having a little problem. I made an app, but I can not make the back of the phone button, return to the previous page without completely closing the app. I'm working with WebView.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        // CODIGO DO WEB VIEW

        final WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.idestudos.com.br");
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());

        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() { //CODE WEBVIEW}
```

Comment: Is there anything relevant in your logcat? My money would be on a NullPointerException, or at least an exception of some variety.

Comment: Check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageStarted to handle URL changes. You may need to keep storing the actual URL (everytime the URL gets updated) that your WebView is loading, and then override the onBackPressed() method so your app loads the previous URL in your WebView instead of finishing the whole Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution:

When your WebView overrides URL loading, it automatically accumulates a history of visited web pages. You can navigate backward and forward through the history with goBack() and goForward().

For example, here's how your Activity can use the device Back button to navigate backward:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
// Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
    myWebView.goBack();
    return true;
}
// If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
// system behavior (probably exit the activity)
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Check out the [Building Web Apps in WebView](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) Android Developers Guide for more info

Hope it helps you!

Comment: insert out of the OnCreate method?

Comment: insert it wherever you create your webview and initialise it. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Easy implemented by calling canGoBack.

```
    if(webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    }
```

And calling it from inside onBackPressed method in activity like this:

```
@Override public void onBackPressed() {

    if(webView != null && webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to also `return` a `onKeyDown` also. Otherwise if the user hits the backbutton and there's no history nothing will happen.

Comment: Nope, as long as you dont return super.onBackPressed he should be fine.

Comment: You need to `return onBackPressed` if `webView.canGoBack()` is false . And I see you have edited your answer

Comment: Cheers! Glad I could help.